# How to get all images with src not empty?

Tags: jquery

How to get all images in an html with src not empty.

I want to use jquery to select images which just have scr attr not empty.

how to write this jquery selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("img[src!='']")
```

Comment: this is not empty src? so how empty src  should be?

Comment: img[src] will select any img element with it's src not empty.

Comment: I was actually wrong, haha. I thought that too Pim -- I just tried it, but if you do that, it'll select elements like this as well:
<img src="" />
Which is obviously not the best. This works though, according to some testing:
$("a[rel!='']")